# How can I fix race condition in this "reset after time" observable?

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive, race-condition, throttling

Input is an observable that produces a value each time a problem occurs.

As output I want an observable that produces a value if problems exist for a longer time. In other words I want to "reset" the output observable (not produce values) if the last problem is outdated.

My solution:

```
// first get an observable producing statusOk values (true = ok, false = not ok)
var okStatusObservable = input.Select(_ => true).Throttle(longerTime)
                  .Merge(input.Select(_ => false));


// we only want event if statusOk=false for a longer time
var outputObservable = okStatusObservable
                  .DistinctUntilChanged() // only changes
                  .Throttle(evenLongerTime) // wait for stable status
                  .Where(_ => _ == false); // only interested in bad status
```

I think the `okStatusObservable` might contain a race condition: If input receives events at time interval of exactly `longerTime` and second merge part (`Select` / `false`) would produce a boolean before the first part (`Select`+`Throttle` / `true`) then this would result in okStatus to be `true` 99.9% of the time where the opposite would be correct.

(PS: to have status value from beginning, we might add `.StartWith(true)` but that doesn't matter regarding race condition.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleaner way to do the first observable is as follows:

```
var okStatusObservable2 = input
    .Select(_ => Observable.Return(true).Delay(longerTime).StartWith(false))
    .Switch();
```

Explanation: For each `input` message, produce an observable that starts with a false, and after `longerTime` produces a true. The `Switch` means that if you have a new observable, just switch to it, which would exclude the all-clear `true` at the end.

For your second observable, unless `longerTime` differs between the two observables, every first `false` in the first observable will result in a `false` in the second. Is that your intention?

Also, your `Where` is messed up (should be `.Where(b => !b)` or `.Where(b => b == false)`. `.Where(_ => false)` will always evaluate to false returning nothing.

Other than that, I think your solution is sound.

Comment: Thanks for this `Switch` solution, looks very clean to me.

Regarding `Where`: of course. This was an oversight. I will edit my question for this point just to avoid any confusion for others. Thanks.

Regarding my second observable: Yes, this is intentionally and probably the second longerTime will be a longer delay. Combined with `Take(1)` I just want to get one event to trigger some action to e.g. restart the whole program.

Comment: I lovely clean use of `Observable.Return(true).Delay(longerTime).StartWith(false)`. Nice.